# Как подключить из CSS шрифт к SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, шрифты, svg-animation

На первом изображении не подтянутый шрифт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На во втором изображении, как должен выглядеть сам логотип с примененным шрифтом

[image: Подтянутые стили]

Подключение самого шрифта осуществляю через стили css но фото самого логотипа подключаю через свойство background-image.

Мне нужно подключить svg с примененным шрифтом

```
CSS
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular";
    src: url(../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 3000 3000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 3000 3000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{opacity:0.2;fill:#FECA16;}
    .st1{opacity:0.3;fill:#D6EDF7;}
    .st2{opacity:0.25;fill:#E7A6CB;}
    .st3{fill:#124048;}
    .st4{font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular';}
    .st5{font-size:1275.3042px;}
    .st6{fill:#D88BB4;}
    .st7{font-size:1275.3038px;}
</style>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -2033.9785 -1114.8296)" class="st4" style="display:none; font-size:12px;">УAловите свое</text>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M1002.7,929.9c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1248.8,929.9,1002.7,929.9z M1002.7,1766C787,1766,612,1591.1,612,1375.3S787,984.7,1002.7,984.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1218.5,1766,1002.7,1766z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M1258.4,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1504.5,1320.5,1258.4,1320.5z M1258.4,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1474.2,2156.7,1258.4,2156.7z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M611.7,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S857.8,1320.5,611.7,1320.5z M611.7,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S827.5,2156.7,611.7,2156.7z"/>
    <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 370.7987 1977.4373)" class="st3 st4 st5">E</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 573.8547 2211.6697)" class="st6 st4 st7">F</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: всё предельно ясно - и что вы хотите узнать ? знака вопроса не увидел - так и не понял что требуется

Comment: @MaximLensky Изменил: "Мне нужно подключить svg с примененным шрифтом" а он не подтягивается

Comment: покажите ваш svg и css и html и способ при котором вы подключаете ваш шрифт

Comment: @Locker Начнём с очевидного вопроса: почему вы решили что шрифт должен подтянуться в вашем случае?

Comment: @andreymal В каком случаи он не подтягивается? Я добавил сам шрифт в css. как можно исправить данный случай? Вы нацелены на унижение, или задаете уточняющий вопрос. Я зашел сюда что бы мне подсказали, а не носом тыкали.

Comment: @MaximLensky Правил пост. Комментарий будет слишком большой

Comment: @Locker как конкретно у вас связаны этот svg и этот css? Ваш svg-код не содержит ссылок на этот css.

Comment: @andreymal Я подключил эти стили на сам сайт к которому был добавлен SVG

Comment: @Locker если svg-код не вставлен прямо в html-код и подключен отдельным файлом, то он не будет учитывать стили сайта, так как является отдельным файлом и не имеет к сайту никакого отношения

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо)

Comment: @Locker и вообще лучше всего преобразовать текст в кривые в ближайшем векторном редакторе и не мучаться с подключением шрифтов, в логотипе шрифты ни к чему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению шрифт `MyriadPro-Regular` является [платным Adobe шрифтом](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/myriad?src=GoogleFonts) - **35$**
Если вы делаете лого для вебсайта, то лучше его **не использовать** или купить.

Но можно подобрать бесплатный аналог этому шрифту - `Open Sans`

В этом случае подключение шрифта из HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

CSS

```
.st4{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
    .st5{font-size:900px;}
    .st6{fill:#D88BB4;}
    .st7{font-size:900px;}
```

Полный код:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 900 3000 3000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 3000 3000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{opacity:0.2;fill:#FECA16;}
    .st1{opacity:0.3;fill:#D6EDF7;}
    .st2{opacity:0.25;fill:#E7A6CB;}
    .st3{fill:#124048;}
    .st4{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
    .st5{font-size:1275.3042px;}
    .st6{fill:#D88BB4;}
    .st7{font-size:1275.3038px;}
</style>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -2033.9785 -1114.8296)" class="st4" style="display:none; font-size:12px;">УAловите свое</text>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M1002.7,929.9c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1248.8,929.9,1002.7,929.9z M1002.7,1766C787,1766,612,1591.1,612,1375.3S787,984.7,1002.7,984.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1218.5,1766,1002.7,1766z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M1258.4,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1504.5,1320.5,1258.4,1320.5z M1258.4,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1474.2,2156.7,1258.4,2156.7z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M611.7,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S857.8,1320.5,611.7,1320.5z M611.7,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S827.5,2156.7,611.7,2156.7z"/>
    <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 370.7987 1977.4373)" class="st3 st4 st5">E</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 573.8547 2211.6697)" class="st6 st4 st7">F</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Пример со шрифтом **Lobster**

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 900 3000 3000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 3000 3000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{opacity:0.2;fill:#FECA16;}
    .st1{opacity:0.3;fill:#D6EDF7;}
    .st2{opacity:0.25;fill:#E7A6CB;}
    .st3{fill:#124048;}
    .st4{font-family: Lobster;}
    .st5{font-size:1275.3042px;}
    .st6{fill:#D88BB4;}
    .st7{font-size:1275.3038px}
</style>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -2033.9785 -1114.8296)" class="st4" style="display:none; font-size:12px;">УAловите свое</text>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M1002.7,929.9c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1248.8,929.9,1002.7,929.9z M1002.7,1766C787,1766,612,1591.1,612,1375.3S787,984.7,1002.7,984.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1218.5,1766,1002.7,1766z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M1258.4,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S1504.5,1320.5,1258.4,1320.5z M1258.4,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S1474.2,2156.7,1258.4,2156.7z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M611.7,1320.5c-246.1,0-445.6,199.5-445.6,445.6s199.5,445.6,445.6,445.6s445.6-199.5,445.6-445.6
        S857.8,1320.5,611.7,1320.5z M611.7,2156.7c-215.8,0-390.7-174.9-390.7-390.7s174.9-390.7,390.7-390.7s390.7,174.9,390.7,390.7
        S827.5,2156.7,611.7,2156.7z"/>
    <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 370.7987 1977.4373)" class="st3 st4 st5">E</text>
        <text transform="matrix(1.3218 0 -0.2588 0.9659 573.8547 2211.6697)" class="st6 st4 st7">F</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```